# How to use LUIS and FormFlow together in one chatbot

Tags: c#, botframework, chat, chatbot

I'm having a situation, From where user first utterance will give us the LUIS intent and entities, if any entities are missing then chatbot should prompt user for the it.

Example: We have accommodation booking chatbot. Where user can ask query or book apartments.
First Chatbot will pro-actively greet the user **"Good Morning, I am AccommodationBot, How may I help you today?"**. 
User may reply **"i’d like to make a reservation on 10 Feb"**
From the above utterance the LUIS will understand the intent **BookAnApartment**. The entities are **Reservation, 10 Feb etc..**
Still bot need some more information about the user like **name,email,phone, duration of stay etc...** 
How do the chatbot will prompt user for the information one after another like formflow?

Comment: Are you trying to use the Bot Builder SDK v3 instead of v4?

Comment: Yes! I am using SDK3 @KyleDelaney

Comment: I need to stress very strongly that all new bots should be developed in v4. The more work you do on this v3 bot, the more work it will be for you to migrate later. Are you willing to switch to v4 now?

Comment: Thank you. Yes @KyleDelaney I want to switch but I think v4 is on .net core. Is it available in .Net Framework? Please please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: There are some instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-framework) that explain how to migrate in place to the .NET Framework v4 SDK. But is there a reason you don't want to switch to a .NET Core project?

Comment: Are you still working on this?